# Sharing of information and borrowing of strength. What models are there

Tags: random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, pooling, exchangeability

I am currently working on identifying all the methods that have been implemented in all kinds of disciplines in order to borrow strength. If you have ever used, or came across such methods i would be grateful if you could let me enrich my collection.

To make myself more clear with regards to the 'borrowing of strength' i will give some examples. If you are trying to synthesize data from a lot of different trials that estimate a particular treatment effect you could simply assume that

1. all trials estimate a specific treatment effect and thus you effectively imply that all the treatments are the same and do the so called 'lumping'.
2. alternatively, one could say that the treatment effects are not the same but similar, or more formally exchangeable, and thus they all belong to a distribution; thus effectively assuming random effects and borrowing strength from that common distribution
3. If the treatment effects now are evidently not exchangeable, then one could maybe cluster the treatment effects and assume partial exchangeability by using some random partition model

4.
5.
6.

7. In the very end one acknowledges that all  treatment effects are distinct from each other and has to run a meta-regression.

What other methods to you know to 'share information'/'borrow strength' ?

Answer (score 0):

One very basic form of *borrowing strength* is pooling, say of means or variances (or other statistics) when one has reason to believe this  mean/variances/... are (approximately) equal in some (sub)populations.